# AppleScript to click Wi-Fi icon with option down

Tags: macos, applescript, osascript

I would like to click on the Wi-Fi icon with the option key down to reveal extra options available on Mac. How can I automate it using AppleScript?

I tried using `key down option` and `click menu item` but no luck in revealing special options.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible to click with a key held down using AppleScript. Key down actions only apply to other key press actions, since the AppleScript click action doesn't actually perform a ‘click’, but rather directly actions the element.

Comment: So there is no way that I can automate this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a 3rd party utility, here's an example **AppleScript** *script* that uses **[`cliclick`](https://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/)**:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "SystemUIServer"
        set theWiFiProperties to item 1 of (get properties of every menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose description starts with "Wi-Fi")
    end tell
    set theXpos to (item 1 of position in theWiFiProperties) + ((item 1 of size in theWiFiProperties) / 2) as integer
    set theYpos to (item 2 of position in theWiFiProperties) + ((item 2 of size in theWiFiProperties) / 2) as integer
end tell
tell current application
    do shell script "/path/to/cliclick kd:alt c:" & theXpos & "," & theYpos & " ku:alt"
end tell
```

- **Note:** Change `/path/to/cliclick` to the actual `pathname` of the `cliclick` executable.

How it works:

The `theWiFiProperties` *variable* gets set to the `properties` of the `Wi-Fi` *menu extra* and then the *variables* `theXpos` and `theYpos` get set to a *position* that together is the *center* of the `Wi-Fi` *menu extra* on the *menu bar*.

This *info* is then used in a `do shell script` *command* using `cliclick` to press the <kbd>option</kbd> key down, click at the designated `x,y` coordinates and let the <kbd>option</kbd> key up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Automator and record the process using “Watch me do” and then save the automated workflow as an application or a dictation command.

[image]

In Automator, I saved the watch me do action as an application.  I named this new application “Extended_Wifi.app”. Then I had to add this application in system preferences to be able to control my computer.

[image]

Personally, I prefer to use Scripteditor rather than Automator because a huge part of me feels like using Automator is cheating.  But at the end of the day, I was able to save the Automator action as an application and it functions perfectly however in Scripteditor, I Could not get the AppleScript version of the action to function correctly.

Here is a quick .gif showing the Automator application working correctly.

[image]

Comment: I tried this. when I execute the code generated by automator it simply click but is not revealing other options.

Comment: In Automator when I started the recording using watch me do, I held down the option key and kept it down as I clicked on the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar

Comment: I did the same. after that I am trying to copy events into script editor so that it will generate the applescript for that . When execute that applescript it is not revealing the extra options.